# Is there way to check feature deprecation against django version?

Tags: python, django, deprecation-warning

As some features get deprecated with new versions of Django, is there a way to check for that on an existing project code say on github.

Could a tool do that. Is there a way to detect that through testcases.

Would it be possible to do the same against a python version.

I guess one way could be to run through a specific version of django / python using tox and then check for errors.

I am just looking for something more elegant or direct, something like which says - ***"Note this feature has been deprecated"***, something which can be done in strongly typed language like Java.

If one wanted to build such a tool, what could be starting point for that, if possible.

Comment: Great question, I too miss the code inspection available in Java IDEs. Also, having warnings for missed exceptions / errors to catch is very helpful, rather than trying to find them manually or waiting til they show up in production.

Answer (score 2):

I think this would have to be in the unit tests for your project.

If your tests exercise code that will be deprecated in a future version of Django you will get [warnings](https://docs.python.org/2/library/warnings.html). If you've jumped to a version of Django where the feature is already deprecated you'll get exceptions and failed tests of course.

You can [tell the Python interpreter](https://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-W) to promote warnings to exceptions, which would cause tests to fail.

Instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20998338/202168) to apply the same trick to the popular [nosetests](https://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) test framework.

If you know already (from Django docs) that some code you're writing will need to change depending on Django version it is run under (eg you're distributing a reusable Django app) I would suggest a form of [feature detection](http://learn.jquery.com/code-organization/feature-browser-detection/#specific-feature-detection) using `try ... except`

For example, here I wanted to conditionally use the [new `transaction.atomic` feature](https://github.com/anentropic/django-exclusivebooleanfield/blob/0.1.2/exclusivebooleanfield/fields.py#L5) from Django >= 1.6: .

As you anticipated, I then run the tests against different versions of Django with the [help of Tox](https://github.com/anentropic/django-exclusivebooleanfield/blob/0.1.2/tox.ini).

Answer (score 2):

This is how I got tox to run one project of mine against Django 1.6, 1.7 and 1.8 with deprecation warnings on:

```
[tox]
envlist = {py27,py34}-{django16,django17,django18}

[testenv]
basepython =
           py27: python2.7
           py34: python3.4

deps =
     django16: Django>=1.6,<1.7
     django17: Django>=1.7,<1.8
     django18: Django>=1.8,<1.9

commands =
         python -Wmodule ./manage.py test
```

The `-Wmodule` argument causes Python to output each deprecation warning the first time it occurs in a module, which was good enough for me. I was able to deal with instances where I used `from django.core.cache import get_cache`, which will be gone in Django 1.9.

In cases where `-Wmodule` outputs too much, you might want to be more selective. Python's documentation gives the [lowdown on how to use this argument](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-W). I've *purposely* not used `-Werror` because this would not just make the individual tests fail but would make my test suite fail to execute *any* test because the suite uses deprecated features.